# Can a WebRtc signaling server find ICE candidates for clients without an extra STUN server

Tags: webrtc, kurento, stun

I am working on a WebRtc application to broadcast video to my clients. I use Kurento as the WebRtc media server and use Spring Boot to build my signaling server. There is only media data that flows from my media server to clients but no media data in the opposite direction. So the media server's public address is not needed while clients's public addresses are required. That is I need to find ICE candidates that contains public address for my clients.

I know clients can setup up an extra stun server to achieve this. But since the clients are already talking to my signaling server, is it possible that I just use my signaling server to find ICE candidates for the clients?

Answer (score 1):

A stun server lets the client figure out a UDP port where other clients can connect. This is different from the TCP connection the client uses to connect to your signaling server.

If you client is only talking to your media server, that is not needed. However, you may need a TURN server to allow connections from networks that block UDP (unless your media server supports ICE-TCP)